# SQL Server to MySQL migration, replace '\xA0' with a regular space

Tags: sql-server, mysql, t-sql, migration, collation

I am having some trouble while migrating data from SQL Server to MySQL--it seems some data does not want to place nice. I am recieving the error: `Incorrect string value: '\xA0\xA0' for column 'Address1'`

As I am trying to automate data migrations that will happen regularly, I need to find a solution I can put into a script. I am using **wbcopytables.exe** at the moment, but I do not necessarily need to.

In just trying to find an appropriate solution to later implement in the script, I have tried running the below in SQL Server to fix the source data:

```
UPDATE [ForgeDB].[Snapshot].[SnapshotPersonEmployee]
SET Address1 = REPLACE(Address1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, N'\xA0', ' ')
```

and

```
UPDATE [ForgeDB].[Snapshot].[SnapshotPersonEmployee]
SET Address1 = REPLACE(Address1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, N'\u00A0', ' ')
```

but that is not fixing the source data, and my Google-Fu is failing me. Thoughts?

Comment: What charset are you using for the conversion?  For the target table?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use CHARINDEX casting your Address1 to varbinary(8000) to identify the offending data:

```
select * 
from [ForgeDB].[Snapshot].[SnapshotPersonEmployee]
where charindex(0xA0, cast(Address1 as varbinary(8000))) > 0;
```

Check this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37355/55596